# How to create a new image format?

Tags: java, image, file, header, format

I have been playing around with some image processing tools in java and was wondering how to create my own image format (with its own file extension and header).

Say I am trying to store 2 jpeg images into a new file with extension .abcde

How would I approach this and modify the file header? 
I did some research and found this, but it didnt have any sort of example.
https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-custom-binary-file-formats-for-your-games-data--gamedev-206

Any advice/references/examples would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Here you should ask yourself a question — what is binary file? It is some type of "box" that contains 8-bit values (0-255 range). And what actually images are? The same. But data in images is stored specifically. If you look at bitmaps (*.BMP files) for example, you'll see that it contains RGB values (it actually depends on the color depth, but we are talking about 24-bit colors now). So, what does it mean? It means that each pixel is stored with 3 bytes (24 bits) for Red Green and Blue values. 
EG: 0x00 0x00 0x00 — This is black pixel in hex representation
0xFF 0xFF 0xFF — White.
But storing image data in such way is quite inefficient. For example, 1024x1024 image would be 1024*1024*3=3145728 bytes!!  Or 3 MEGABYTES. And that is not including alpha channel, which also stored with one byte.
 So, here the data compression comes in, it can be lossy or lossless. If you open for example a PNG file in the hex editor, you'll see a DEFLATE compressed data (LZ77+Huffman coding). It is lossless.
 GIF files are compressed with LZW, which is quite inefficient nowadays. There lots of really nice image formats such as FLIF or BPG, which compress images better than PNG and JPEG.
  So, if you want to create your own file format, you can create just a raw pixel container file (like BMP or PCX), or compressed pixel file (here you should write a custom data compression algorithm, C or C++ suits the best for this purpose).